# X-axis interval in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, intervals

[image: My highcharts graph]

I have this highchart graph displayed on my website. How can I set an interval for my x-axis? e.g. I want the fist value to be displayed and then skip the second and display the third.
Can this be done? Or do you always just HAVE to display all the data you're passing to the axis in an array?

My code: (timestamp is a JS array that contains my time. I can get that time in epoch format. act and temps are arrays for data to be plotted along y-axis)

```
$(function () {
    $('#tempactgraph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature & Activity Monitoring '
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Cowlar Sensors'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: timestamp,
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Activity',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} xx',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Activities',
            type: 'spline',
        connectNulls: 1,
            yAxis: 1,
            data: act,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' xx'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
        connectNulls: 1,
            data: temps,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you use categories or datetime? Could you recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: This is the link of the jsfiddle-> http://jsfiddle.net/6xLaxL0e/4/
In x-axis, I'm using categories. And I'm passing an array to all three axis!

Comment: Set tickInterval as 2 like here: http://jsfiddle.net/6xLaxL0e/5/ but better is using datetime xAxis instead of categories.

Comment: How do I do that? I've edited my question and posted my actual code till yet!

Comment: tickInterval: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add a `tickInterval:2` to your x-axis decleration like so

```
xAxis: [{
            categories: timestamp,
            crosshair: true,
            tickInterval: 2
        }],
```

[Highcharts API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval)

Comment: Did that. Thank you! :)